# Windows 10 Home: is it possible to switch to Semi-Annual Channel instead of Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Unlike Pro/Enterprise edition of Windows 10, Home edition does not have UI to select preferred update channel. Here is the options available in Pro edition:
[image]

Based on [MSFT documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-servicing-channels-windows-10-updates) Home edition only allows use of Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted) and Insider channels, but I'm wondering if we can force it to use Semi-Annual Channel (formerly known as CBB)?

Comment: No, It cannot per the MS documentation.  That channel basically is how you defer feature updates.  Upgrade to professional if you want to use that channel